# ArcGIS : Labels only rendered at 10,000,000 scale

Tags: gis, arcgis, esri, arcmap

I'm using ArcGIS Server 9.3 with an Oracle 10.2g database. I've created an MXD which contains my feature class and I've configured it to show one of the attributes as a label - both the feature class and the label are set to be visible at all scales.

In ArcMap, the labels only show at a scale of 1:10,000,000 - as soon as I zoom in they disappear.

I'm doing 2 things in an 'non-standard' way:

1. The feature class is created by importing a schema via the geodatabase designer plugin for ArcCatalog - after the import I register as versioned with move edits to base
2. I'm inserting my data using sql - as shown here:

```
    INSERT
   INTO MYTABLE
  (
    OBJECTID,
    LABEL   ,
    SHAPE
  )
  VALUES
  (
    sde.version_user_ddl.next_row_id('MYSCHEMA',2712)  ,
    'SHOWME'                                           ,
    sde.st_geometry('POINT  ( 9689097.37142934 4423553.842365312)', 4)
  );
```

So, when visualising this in ArcMap, I see the points okay, but the labels are only rendered when I zoom to full extent. Layer and labels are set to show at all scales.

Is anyone doing anything similar, or can you suggest any fixes?

Comment: You say that "I've created an MXD". This is in ArcMap right? How have you configured the map to show labels?

Comment: yes, made mxd via arcmap and turned labels on for all scales.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have been able to work around this problem by setting the extent of the layer - I know the full extent that my application up front so this is easy and appropriate:

sdelayer -o alter -l MYTABLE,SHAPE -E 8714580.0881,4024165.7422,9950152.555,5045059.3021 -s SERVERNAME -i 5151:MYSCHEMA_sde -u MYSCHEMA -p PASSWORD